# Room + RxJava = GC?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android, android-room

I have my app with `Room + RxJava2`.

Here is my **DAO**:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM calendar")
Maybe<List<EventModel>> getAll();
```

**Repository:**

```
calendarDao.getAll()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(calendarDays -> {
                if (calendarDatabaseCallback != null)
                    calendarDatabaseCallback.onCalendarItemsLoaded(calendarDays);
            });
```

Problem is - when I call this method and when I am trying to get from `DB` many records (in above example I have about 500) `GC` is being called about 20 times with similar message:

```
GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8026K, 13% free 60595K/69048K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
```

Shouldn't `Rx` with Subscriber on `Schedulers.io` be responsible for working on a new `thread` without touching `UI`?

Comment: what does it (which thread is used) have to do with GC activity?

Comment: I understand that thread has nothing to do with GC. I don't get why executing pretty simple query with not huge amount of records is calling GC and making device slowing down. Is this really so much of data? I have about 10 columns in DAO.

Comment: `"not huge amount of records"` means ... ?

Comment: As mentioned in the main topic - 500

Comment: oh sorry i missed that, tried [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)? here is the [sample](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html#sample) room related code

Comment: I won't lie, sometimes I have noticed calling `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` will ultimately skip the IO scheduler and run on the main thread. Often leading to either blocked frames or `MainThread` exception.